# Is there anything wrong/confusing with the notation $F'(t) = \frac {d}{dt}[G(t, t)](t)?$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $G(u, t): \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and let $F(t) = G(t, t)$. Is there anything wrong/confusing about the following notation?
$$F'(t) = \frac{d}{dt}[G(t, t)](t)$$
My professor said the RHS is confusing, but here's how I think about it. Take the function which assigns $G(t, t)$ to $t$ for arbitrary $t$, differentiate it with respect to $t$ (i.e. differentiate w.r.t. the only variable the function has), and then plug in the $t$ that is the actual value we're evaluating at on the LHS, which we also happened to denote by $t$.

If this is confusing, what is a better way to write it?

Comment: $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} G(t,t)$ already contains a $t$ -- there is no place to put an argument.  What does $\left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} x^2 \right)(x)$ mean?  The result of the derivative has no place to put the argument specified by "$(x)$".

Comment: *A* (redundant) way to capture what you write would be $$  \left. \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u} G(u,u) \right) \right|_{u = t}  \text{,}  $$ but this is unnecessary -- $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} G(t,t)$ is already a function with $t$ as its variable.

Comment: IMO total derivatives are really applied to expressions, not functions. You can substitute into that expression, and that substitution operation technically produces a function, but still the differentiation operation made an expression. So $\frac{d}{dt} G(t,t)$ already makes sense. That said, what you said can *technically* make sense because the second $t$ is in a scope where it can be a fixed constant, so the first three $t$'s are different $t$'s than the last one.

Comment: (Cont.) But that is extremely confusing; normally people use $t_0$ or similar symbols for such constant values if they are too close to a variable symbol.

Comment: @Ian What do you mean by "total derivative"? To me this means Frechet derivative, but I don't see how that's involved here. Do you mean the symbol $\frac {d}{dt}$ is applied to expressions, and not functions?

Comment: @user56202 I mean $\frac{d}{dt}$ as opposed to $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ as a partial derivative. $\frac{d}{dt}$ requires you to specify how the arguments other than $t$ depend on $t$ (if at all).

Comment: @EricTowers But I find $\frac {d}{dt} G(t, t)$ confusing. In expressing $F'(t)$ , we want to illustrate $3$ things for the reader: 1) take a derivative 2) of the function $t \mapsto G(t, t)$ 3) at the particular point $t$. When you write $\frac {d}{dt} G(t, t)$ do your $t's$ refer the the $t's$ in step $2$ or $3$? In either case, you are representing just one step, and suppressing the other.

Comment: @Ian Would you be so kind as to have a look at my comment to EricTowers above? I think this is the crux of the confusion for me.

Comment: So first off I want to go off-topic a little and say this is taught badly in multivariable calculus and that part of why it is taught badly is because the usage isn't entirely consistent among authors. That said, the way I see $\frac{d}{dt} G(t,t)$ is as an expression depending on a variable $t$ with no definite value. The syntax for substituting into this without introducing a function is $\left. \frac{d}{dt} G(t,t) \right |_{t=t_0}$. If you're going to do this substitution a lot then you should introduce a function to cut out some syntactic cruft.

Comment: @Ian Oh okay so in $F'(t) = \frac {d}{dt}G(t, t)$, the $t$ on the $LHS$ is not actually represented at all. But it would be represented if we had the actual $G$ (such as $G(u, t) = ue^t$ since then $\frac {d}{dt}G(t, t) = \frac {d}{dt}[te^t] = e^t + te^t$. And you view $\frac {d}{dt}G(t, t)$ as an expression of $t$ and not really as a function of $t$, so you would also be against the notation $\left[ \frac {d}{dt}G(t, t) \right](t)$. Is this correct?

Comment: "Against" is a slightly stronger word than I would use here. I can read it, but I have to think about what the author likely wants to communicate rather than just reading what is literally in front of me, because of the abrupt change in the scoping of the symbol $t$. But yes, the expression vs. function distinction is confusing. I have graded so, so many Matlab questions that were wrong because of this issue...

Comment: @Ian Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge, you've cleared up things significantly for me. Just to make sure I understand, when I write $\frac {d}{dt} [G(t, t)](3)$, to you this is literally like writing $(t^3 + 3t^2 - t)(3)$, which you have to go through the mental gymnastic of interpreting it as "the function $t \mapsto t^3 + 3t^2 - t"$ evaluated at $3$.

Comment: Yes, that's a good analogy for the way I think about it. (Although that case has a further defect in that it could be misunderstood as multiplication).

Comment: @Ian I see. I am very grateful for your help in clearing this up!

Comment: For anyone arriving at this Question and comments who is still confused: Let $f(x) = x^2$.  What is $f'(2)$?  It is the function $f'$, the derivative of $f$ with no formal parameter specified, evaluated by binding the formal parameter to the value $2$, so it is the value $4$.  Similarly, $f'(x)$ is the derivative of $f$ with its formal parameter bound to the independent variable $x$ -- it is not a function, so "$f'(x)(2)$" does not denote a function evaluated at $2$; it denotes an expression in $x$ followed by "$(x)$", which would mean multiplication by $x$.

Comment: @EricTowers I think you meant "an expression in $x$ followed by "$(2)$" which would mean multiplication by $2$".

Comment: @Ian : Yes, that is what I meant.  <sigh>